# Install netifaces to local directory

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip

I am trying to get the python module netifaces installed locally into a project dir in order to use it with an AWS lambda function. I did it the following way:

```
cd projectdir
pip install netifaces -t .
```

In the project I used:

```
from netifaces import interfaces, AF_INET, ifaddresses
```

And on lambda aws I get the error that it can not find the module netifaces. 
How would I resolve this?

Comment: I realize this does not solve your problem, but it seems worth asking why you need something like `netifaces`.  It isn't likely that you are going to learn anything useful with it in the Lambda environment, but there may be exceptions I haven't thought of.  What are you planning to do with this?

Comment: I am planning to use this in AWS GreenGrass on a Pi in my local network for an api which requires local ip addresses.